# How do you iterate over ARGV and create a Thread for each value in the array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading, sass, compass-sass, compass

I'm trying to create a Ruby script that launches a separate thread for each of the arguments passed in ARGV, but I can't figure out how to iterate over them and pass them in the thread as constants (or thread-safe). Something like:

## compile.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'compass'
require 'compass/exec'

threads = []
ARGV.each do |arg|
  threads << Thread.new { Compass::Exec::SubCommandUI.new(["compile", arg]).run! }
end
threads.each { |thr| thr.join }
```

The result is that it will create the expected number of threads, but each thread will run on the same arg value (the loop doesn't work as expected).

I'm trying to run it from Ant, like this:

## build.xml

```
<java fork="true" failonerror="true" classpathref="jruby.classpath" classname="org.jruby.Main">
    <arg path="${ext.path}\compile.rb"></arg>
    <arg line="${config.rb.dirs.str}"></arg>
</java>
```

where "config.rb.dirs.str" contains my paths to multiple Sass projects, space separated.

I'm a newbie in Ruby, so please don't judge. Thanks!

Comment: *"each thread will run on the same arg value"* -- I don't see why that would happen; your code looks fine to me. How are you running the script? (What command do you type into the console?)

Comment: I edited the question to include my java callback in Ant which is used to call the ruby script

Comment: it is weird because if I just do a "print arg" inside the thread, that works fine, which makes me think the problem is coming from the Compass::Exec::SubCommandUIs running in parallel.

Comment: What does `ARGV` *actually* equal? Is it `["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]`, or `["arg1 arg2 arg3"]`? Use `p ARGV`, or `puts ARGV.inspect` to see. My *suspicion* is that `<arg line="..."` is cramming everything into a single argument, but I cannot say without more information.

Comment: I tried `p ARGV` and `puts ARGV.inspect` and they both output `["arg1", "arg2", "arg3"]`

Comment: OK, then going back to my original point: *"each thread will run on the same arg value"* - I don't know what you mean. The `each` loop should go through each item in that array. Can you produce a minimal example that reproduces your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you run following and tell us the output?
You can run it with args or use the default args that are specified in the script. 
It is just two ways of passing variables (i prefer the second one). I think this is a minimal sample that does not require anything extra.

```
args = ARGV.size > 0 ? ARGV : ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']

puts "args is #{args} and has size #{args.size}"
threads = args.map do |arg|
  Thread.new do
    sleep 1
    print "Arg is: #{arg}\n"
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)

puts "--"


threads = args.map do |arg|
  Thread.new(arg) do |value|
    sleep 1
    print "Arg is: #{value}\n"
  end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, they both output the arguments as expected. It must be the **Compass::Exec::SubCommandUI** that is actually not thread safe.

Comment: I actually solved my problem with `sleep 1` added outside the `Thread.new` in the args iteration loop...

Comment: I don't think that this is a proper solution to the error you are seeing.